# Using Webpack to turn TypeScript into es5

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-5

I've created a really simple environment to experiment with TypeScript and Webpack. I've followed online examples as best I could but the output of the build contains `() =>`, which should have been changed to ES5 syntax. Note that I'm NOT using Babel - as far as I can tell TypeScript should be able to produce ES5 without it.

Here is part of my package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "8.0.7",
    "typescript": "4.0.3",
    "webpack": "5.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es2020",
        "target": "ES5",
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

Here is the webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'my-library.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
};
```

Here is src/index.ts:

```
export const myObj = {
    visual: "the visual",
    audio: "the audio"
}
```

After I do `npm run build` I get the following in dist/my-library.js:

```
(()=>{"use strict";var r={607:(r,e,t)=>{}},e={};function t(o){if(e[o])return e[o].exports;var n=e[o]={exports:{}};return r[o](n,n.exports,t),n.exports}t.d=(r,e)=>{for(var o in e)t.o(e,o)&&!t.o(r,o)&&Object.defineProperty(r,o,{enumerable:!0,get:e[o]})},t.o=(r,e)=>Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(r,e),t(607)})();
```

Notice that the code won't run on old browsers even though I've specified "ES5".

The folder structure is:

```
dist
  my-library.js
src
  index.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [webpack typescript docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/)

Comment: Yes, that's where a lot of the above came from. It clearly says that `"target": "es5",` should do the trick, but it isn't for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are probably using `webpack5` which introduced support for es6+ as the `target`.
The code that you see, is the code that Webpack generates (it's runtime code), you can specify that it should use `es5`.

```js
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    target: ['web', 'es5']
    // ------ ^
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'my-library.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
};
```

For more options checkout [the docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#root)

Comment: I was thinking it had something to do with webpack's targeting that was causing the OP's problems

Comment: Thanks! The example I saw had that line in the tsconfig.json file instead.

Comment: Was having the same issue but using webpack 4. It worked if I set the target to `es5` in tsconfig and then set the target to `web` in webpack. Incase someone has a similar issue as me. +1 btw, your answer helped me focus in on the cause of the problem!

Comment: Does this mean that "target" does not work anymore in tsconfig.json?

Comment: It is not related, `tsconfig` defines how your code will be transpiled, but not how webpack's "glue" code will be generated

Comment: It definitely matters what the `target` is in `tsconfig.json`, at least in the latest version of Webpack. If you don't specify `ES5` there, Webpack will generate some output with ES6+ syntax that will break ES5 browsers.

Comment: For me `target: 'es5'` produced errors but `target: ['web', 'es5']` worked

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Webpack 5, the documentation says:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  target: ['web', 'es5'],
};
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#string-1